# Difference between RuntimeException and Exception in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have certain scenarios where I need to raise an exception in my Python code. When I looked at certain examples , I see both raise Exception() and raise RuntimeException() being used. When should I use one over the other?

Comment: How about you create your own custom exception? Inheriting from `Exception` since you can read in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Exception) that "All user-defined exceptions should also be derived from this class.".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Exception) is a superclass for all other normal exception classes.  Choosing this class doesn't convey much information to the caller; you should try to use something more specific.

There is no `RuntimeException`, but there is [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError).  Its documentation states:

> Raised when an error is detected that doesn’t fall in any of the other categories.

("The other categories" being all of the other builtin exception classes)

Comment: So they are equivalent?